# Rally-rest-api v2.21 updateCollection can not work

Tags: java, rally

I want to batch add some defects through rally-rest-api v2.21, but met error as below:

Caused by: java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 405 Could not find web service for �/project/xxxxx/remove.js¼ using request method �POST¼. However a service does exist at that path using method(s) �GET¼.

Please give me a hand, Thanks.

my code snippet:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray defItem = new JsonArray();
for (DefectBean defect : defects)
{
  defItem.add(jsonParser.parse(gson.toJson(defect)));
}
CollectionUpdateRequest defectTCollectionAddRequest = new CollectionUpdateRequest(collectionRef, defItem, true);
CollectionUpdateResponse defectTagCollectionAddResponse = restApi.updateCollection(defectTCollectionAddRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your collectionRef?  And what do your defect items look like?  The updateCollection method is for adding/removing items from a collection as documented here:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/rest_collections.jsp